# Perl regex to recognize multiple strings

Tags: perl

I have a file `~/foo.txt` that has instances of each of the following strings

```
alpha-1
alpha-2
alpha-3
alpha-4
alpha-5
alpha-6
alpha-7
alpha-8
alpha-9
```

I would like to replace each of these `alpha-X` with `beta-X`. Simply replacing `alpha-` with `beta-` will not suffice as there are other instances of `alpha-` that I want to preserve.

I imagine this can be accomplished with something like

```
perl -p -i -e `s/alpha-SOMETHING/beta-SOMETHING/g'
```

but I'm not sure what `SOMETHING` should be. Is there a solution here?

(Of course, I could run nine one-liners but this seems very inefficient.)

Comment: Replace `SOMETHING` like `s/alpha(-[[:digit:]])\b/beta$1/g`

Comment: @brian, you will have to be painfully explicit: which alphas should be replaced and which should be kept?

Comment: @Costas, perl offers the shorthand `\d` for `[[:digit:]]`

Comment: I don't see 0 in the list, so [1-9] might be appropriate here.

Comment: Note, that you're first quote is not correct.

Answer (score 1):

```
perl -p -i -e 's/alpha-(\d)/beta-$1/g'
```

- `\d` matches 0...9
- `(\d)` captures (saves) what was matched and assigns it to the `$1` variable (if you add another capture it would be assigned to the next variable `$2`)
- if the number can have more than one digit you can use `\d+` to match one-or-more digits.

Answer (score 1):

This is the perfect use-case for a [lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
's/alpha(?=-\d)/beta/'
```

This will replace `alpha` with `beta` only if it is followed by `-\d`.